# Code explanation js

Tags: javascript

Wondering if someone can explain what this code means. What do the different lines mean and do?

```
function overlay(theTitle) {
  el = document.getElementById("overlay");
  el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
  el.innerHTML = theTitle;
}

function vindu(){
  el=document.getElementById("vindu");
  el.style.visibility=(el.style.visibility=="visible")?"hidden":"visible";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
el = document.getElementById("overlay");
```

searches an element in your html markup with the ID=overlay

```
el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
```

sets the visibility style of the object to visible if it was hidden before and vice versa.

```
el.innerHTML = theTitle;
```

sets the innerHTML property to the variable which got passed in to the function. innerHTML is actually the content of the element and will show as text in your site

the other method does exactly the same for the element ID = vindu

Answer (score 1):

The only piece of this code that shouldn't be fairly self-explanatory is called the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (also called ternary).

For an example of how this works, `val = test ? 'foo' : 'bar'` is equivalent to the following:

```
if (test) {
    val = 'foo';
} else {
    val = 'bar';
}
```